# How to check a type is of a given template type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I have a template type:

```
template<class T>
struct Shadow {
   T field[100];
};
```

I want to create a `tuple`, whose types are instantiations of `Shadow`, but should not allow any other types. For example,

```
tuple< Shadow<int>, Shadow<double> > x; // correct instantiation.
tuple< Shadow<int>, double > x; // incorrect instantiation.
```

How can I achieve this (and have compiler flag an error in case of incorrect instantiation)?

Comment: Is the `tuple` the `std::tuple` or a class you define?

Comment: it need not be std::tuple, I can do wraping.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I can imagine is wrap the tuple in a variadic template struct (or class)

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct Shadow
 { T field[100]; };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct wrapTShadow
 { std::tuple<Shadow<Ts>...> val; };

int main ()
 {
   // contain a std::tuple<Shadow<int>, Shadow<double>>
   wrapTShadow<int, double>  wts;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Can you tell me what std::tuple<Shadow<Ts>...> does? I am puzzled that you can call Shadow<Ts> although "struct Shadow" does not accept variadic templates!

Comment: @user1205476 - you have to distinguish between `std::tuple<Shadow<Ts...>>` and `std::tuple<Shadow<Ts>...>`; suppose that `...Ts` is `T1, T2, T3`; `std::tuple<Shadow<Ts...>>` is unpacked as `std::tuple<Shadow<T1, T2, T3>>` (that is wrong, in your case); `std::tuple<Shadow<Ts>...>` is unpacked as `std::tuple<Shadow<T1>, Shadow<T2>, Shadow<T3>>` (that is what you need, in this case, I suppose)

Comment: @user1205476 - p.s.: look also at the solution from alangab: it's based on the same idea but avoids the need of wrapping struct. Simpler, more elegant and (I suspect) more efficient

Answer (score 2):

You could use type alias:

```
template<class ...Args> 
using shadow_tuple = std::tuple<Shadow<Args>...>;

int main()
{
    shadow_tuple<int, double> xx;
    return 0;
}
```